# .NET 8 GitHub Actions gives "error NETSDK1112: The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded" in Blazor Hybrid Build

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, github-actions, maui

I'm trying to build `Blazor Hybrid` project in Github Actions. Here is my `yml` file,

```yaml
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.4.0

      # Install .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
          
      # Install dotnet buildtools workload
      - name: Install .NET Build Tools
        run: dotnet workload install maui macos ios wasm-tools

      # Restore Dependencies
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
        
      # Build Blazor
      - name: Build Blazor
        run: dotnet build ./Web/Web.csproj --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build Android
      - name: Build Android
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-android --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build IOS
      - name: Build IOS
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-ios --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build Windows
      - name: Build Windows
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win-x64 --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build MacCatalyst
      - name: Build MacCatalyst
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-maccatalyst --configuration Release --no-restore
```

Then `Build Windows` step fails and gives the following error:

```
Run dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win-x64 --configuration Release --no-restore
MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET
Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(491,5): error NETSDK1112: The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'. [D:\a\BlazorHybrid\BlazorHybrid\MAUI\MAUI.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0]
Build FAILED.
Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(491,5): error NETSDK1112: The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'. [D:\a\BlazorHybrid\BlazorHybrid\MAUI\MAUI.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.69
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried specifying `RuntimeIdentifier` as `win-x64` or `win10-x64`. But still the build fails when building for `Windows` `TFM`. Not able to find any proper docs on this. Here is the [repo link](https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid). Please can you assist me on what I'm missing?

Comment: Check https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/7782. Seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understood what is going on wrong here. I need to **remove** the `--no-restore` flag from the build command. So the final command looks like,

`dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64 --configuration Release`

**Source:**

[.NET Conf 2023 session](https://youtu.be/PattkMhmnzE)

[sample GitHub and Azure DevOps build pipelines](https://github.com/Sweekriti91/dotNETConf23DevOps?tab=readme-ov-file)